# https post fails while http post succeeds with almost same code snippet in java?

Tags: java, https

There's a server supports both http and https service. I want to set an access password via java. The problem I met is I managed to do this with http but failed with https. I use the same code except different protocols. Below is my code for setting password:

```
    //url = new URL("http://172.20.1.80/password");
    //HttpURLConnection connection = setHttpConnect((HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection()); 
    url = new URL("https://172.20.1.80/password");
    HttpsURLConnection connection = setHttpsConnect((HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection()); 
    sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    sc.init(null, new TrustManager[] { new MyTrust() }, new java.security.SecureRandom());
    connection.setSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    StringBuffer set = new StringBuffer();
    newpw = "123456"; 
    boundary = "----abc123abc1234-java";
    set.append(boundary + "\r\n").append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"pw\"\r\n\r\n")
            .append(newpw).append("\r\n" + boundary + "--\r\n")
            .append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"con_pw\"\r\n\r\n").append(newpw)
            .append("\r\n" + boundary + "--\r\n");
    out = new PrintWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
    out.write(set.toString());
    out.flush();

    in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
    while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
        result += (str + "\n");
        if (str.indexOf(pwSet) != -1) {
            succ += 1;
            setPwSucc = true;
        }
    }
```

This is the connection attributes:

```
private static HttpsURLConnection setHttpsConnect(HttpsURLConnection c) {
    c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    c.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // timeout
    c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    return c;
}
private static HttpURLConnection setHttpConnect(HttpURLConnection c) {
    c.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "sxf");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3");
    c.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    c.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
    c.setConnectTimeout(timeout); // timeout
    c.setReadTimeout(timeout);
    return (HttpURLConnection) c;
}
```

Setting for X509:

```
public class MyTrust implements X509TrustManager{
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1) throws CertificateException {}
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {return null; }   
}
```

The server can print some logs by webpage, and here are the log seperately:

```
//Log when https in use:
Length of RcvBuf: 336
This is RcvBuf: 
POST /password HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: java Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,app 
lication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding 
: gzip, deflate Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----abc123abc1234-java Host: 172.20.1 
.80 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 203 

//Log when http in use:
Length of RcvBuf: 520
This is RcvBuf: 
POST /password HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: sxf Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,appl 
ication/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 Accept-Language: zh-CN,zh;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3 Accept-Encoding: 
gzip, deflate Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----abc123abc1234-java Host: 172.20.1. 
80 Connection: keep-alive Content-Length: 203 ----abc123abc1234-java Content-Disposition: for 
m-data; name="pd" 123456 ----abc123abc1234-java-- Content-Disposition: form-data; n 
ame="conpw" 123456 ----abc123abc1234-java--
```

It seems when **HTTPS** is in use, my data is not accepted by server.

But one thing confuse me more: there's another operation on the server, and before it is executed, password will be checked. With another code with correct password(the password is set via chrome then), I can execute this operation. Please comment if the code is helpful to analysize the problem.

Can anyone help me to make the https work? My 2nd question is, since I get nothing by the log printed in web page, what is the *203* in `Content-Length: 203`?
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Why are you setting different User-Agents?

Comment: @EJP It seems user-agents is irrelevant. JAVA will set it automatically to 'Java/1.8.0_144'. I tried to set it to variant values including the reasonable one copied from chrome(captured with wireshark). No difference. Can I assume that the server with TLS is not compatiable with my not-so-official post request?